# Serverless - seperate api handlers in config or in code?

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Is there a functional or performance difference between these 2 methods of handling API routes in serverless. Are these the same as far as how memory and container caching will be used?

1. All routes go to same handler which then reroutes internally

serverless.yml

```
functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /foo
      - http: ANY /home
```

handler.js

```
exports.router = async (event, context) => {
  const { path } = event

  switch (path) {
    case '/foo':
      return require('./handlers/foo')(event, context)

   case '/home':
      return require('./handlers/home')(event, context)
      }
}
```

handlers/foo.js

```
module.exports = async (event, context) => {
  ...
};
```

handlers/home.js

```
module.exports = async (event, context) => {
  ...
};
```

2. Assign different handlers per route in serverless.yml

serverless.yml

```
functions:
  apifoo:
    handler: handler.foo 
    events:
      - http: ANY /foo
  apihome:
    handler: handler.home
    events:
      - http: ANY /home
```

handler.js

```
export const foo = async (event, context) => {
  ...
};

export const home = async (event, context) => {
  ...
};
```

Perhaps these will handle the same? I am using method 1 now but want to ensure I am as performant as possible. I understand that aws will reload the lambda on each request but will keep code run outside of lambda itself running for a bit so curious if there is a better setup out of the two.

Comment: But if you are handling the routing in code, you are ending with too much boiler plate and redundant code. Why are you interested in doing so ?

Comment: I mean your app code would be harder to follow. I think is more about separations of concern. am I missing something ?

Comment: Serverless architectures are not the same as conventionals one. That is why you have config and app code splitting in space, but maybe I am not getting your point. Please let me know more about this use case.

Comment: @Luillyfe - the code routing is really some leftover stuff and you are right that its better separated - but thats more of a code management issue. In trying to get my lambda to cold boot faster I started questioning how aws loaded things hence my question. I believe they are the same as far as end performance but wanted to be sure.